# Connecting to Sybase database using Doctrine orm and php7

Tags: php, doctrine, driver, sybase

I am creating a web application in php 7.2 and need to connect to a Sybase database. I am using Doctrine orm.

I have tried using the sqlanywhere driver and the pdo_sqlsrv driver to connect to Sybase.

However with sqlanywhere I am getting the error:

> Warning: sasql_pconnect(): SQLAnywhere: [-832] Connection error: Connection was dropped (may not be a SQL Anywhere server)

With pdo_sqlsrv I get the error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Protocol error in TDS stream.

I have googled both these errors and have not been able to resolve either.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to connect to Sybase using php7.2 and Doctrine orm?

Comment: The error clearly states you're using a MS SQL Server driver - this will not work to connect to a Sybase database.

Comment: Also find out which version of Sybase you're trying to connect to - there are 3 flavours of Sybase (Adaptive Server Enterprise, Adaptive Server Anywhere and Sybase IQ) and there are differences between drivers for each one.